# How to find Orientation of axis of contour in matlab?

Tags: matlab, contour

I want to find `Orientation`, `MajorAxisLength`and `MinorAxisLength` of contour which is plotted with below code.

[image]

```
clear
[x1 , x2] = meshgrid(linspace(-10,10,100),linspace(-10,10,100));
mu = [1,3];
sigm = [2,0;0,2];
xx_size = length(mu);
tem_matrix = ones(size(x1));

x_mesh= cell(1,xx_size);
for i = 1 : xx_size
    x_mesh{i} = tem_matrix * mu(i);
end
x_mesh= {x1,x2};
temp_mesh = [];
for i = 1 : xx_size
    temp_mesh = [temp_mesh x_mesh{i}(:)];
end
Z = mvnpdf(temp_mesh,mu,sigm);
z_plat = reshape(Z,size(x1));
figure;contour(x1, x2, z_plat,3, 'LineWidth', 2,'color','m');

% regionprops(z_plat,'Centroid','Orientation','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength');
```

In my opinion, I may have to use `regionprops` command but I don't know how to do this. I want to find direction of axis of contour and plot something like this

[image]

How can I do this task? Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Rather than messing with an image, why not just use the output of `contour` (the contour matrix itself) to determine these things?

Comment: @Suever Can I find orientation of distribution contour from sigma and plot 2 line with this orientation ? (for my task, having length of lines is not important)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Suever. It help me to do my idea.
I add some line to code:

```
clear
[X1 , X2] = meshgrid(linspace(-10,10,100),linspace(-10,10,100));
mu = [-1,0];
a = [3,2;1,4];
a = a * a';
sigm = a;
xx_size = length(mu);
tem_matrix = ones(size(X1));

x_mesh= cell(1,xx_size);
for i = 1 : xx_size
    x_mesh{i} = tem_matrix * mu(i);
end
x_mesh= {X1,X2};
temp_mesh = [];
for i = 1 : xx_size
    temp_mesh = [temp_mesh x_mesh{i}(:)];
end
Z = mvnpdf(temp_mesh,mu,sigm);
z_plat = reshape(Z,size(X1));
figure;contour(X1, X2, z_plat,3, 'LineWidth', 2,'color','m');
hold on;

% Compute the three contours for your data
contourmatrix = contourc(linspace(-10,10,100), linspace(-10,10,100), z_plat, 3);
% Create a "pointer" to keep track of where we are in the output
start = 1;
count = 1;
% Now loop through each contour
while start < size(contourmatrix, 2)
    value = contourmatrix(1, start);
    nPoints = contourmatrix(2, start);
    contour_points = contourmatrix(:, start + (1:nPoints));
    % Now fit an ellipse using the file exchange
    ellipsedata(count) = fit_ellipse(contour_points(1,:), contour_points(2,:));
    % Increment the start pointer
    start = start + nPoints + 1;
    count = count + 1;
end

orientations = [ellipsedata.phi];  
major_length = [ellipsedata.long_axis];
minor_length = [ellipsedata.short_axis];
tet = orientations(1);
x1 = mu(1);
y1 = mu(2);
a = sin(tet) * sqrt(major_length(1));
b = cos(tet) * sqrt(major_length(1));
x2 = x1 + a;
y2 = y1 + b;

line([x1, x2], [y1, y2],'linewidth',2);

tet = ( pi/2 + orientations(1) );
a = sin(tet) * sqrt(minor_length(1));
b = cos(tet) * sqrt(minor_length(1));
x2 = x1 + a;
y2 = y1 + b;
line([x1, x2], [y1, y2],'linewidth',2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to process the graphical output of `contour`, I would instead recommend using [`contourc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) to compute the [`ContourMatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html#prop_ContourMatrix) and then use the x/y points to estimate the major and minor axes lengths as well as the orientation (for this I used [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3215-fit-ellipse/content/fit_ellipse.m) file exchange submission)

That would look something like the following. Note that I have modified the inputs to `contourc` as the first two inputs should be the vector form and not the output of `meshgrid`.

```
% Compute the three contours for your data
contourmatrix = contourc(linspace(-10,10,100), linspace(-10,10,100), z_plat, 3);

% Create a "pointer" to keep track of where we are in the output
start = 1;
count = 1;

% Now loop through each contour
while start < size(contourmatrix, 2)
    value = contourmatrix(1, start);
    nPoints = contourmatrix(2, start);

    contour_points = contourmatrix(:, start + (1:nPoints));

    % Now fit an ellipse using the file exchange
    ellipsedata(count) = fit_ellipse(contour_points(1,:), contour_points(2,:));

    % Increment the start pointer
    start = start + nPoints + 1;
    count = count + 1;
end

orientations = [ellipsedata.phi];
%   0   0   0   

major_length = [ellipsedata.long_axis];
%   4.7175    3.3380    2.1539

minor_length = [ellipsedata.short_axis];
%   4.7172    3.3378    2.1532
```

As you can see, the contours are actually basically circles and therefore the orientation is zero and the major and minor axis lengths are almost equal. The reason that they look like ellipses in your post is because your x and y axes are scaled differently. To fix this, you can call `axis equal`

```
figure;contour(x1, x2, z_plat,3, 'LineWidth', 2,'color','m');
axis equal
```

[image]